# Calculus exercise

Tags: calculus

I was asked to complete this task but I don't understand how to processed.

Determine if the reservoir is being filled or drained when t=8 second.

$$Q(t)=\frac{6\sqrt[3]{t}}{4t+1}$$

I have been doing some research and I think I have everything I need to differentiate this, but I am a bit confused as to whether I should be doing numerator and denominator then doing the maths, or should I be use the quotient rule to work it out?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $Q(t)$?

Comment: You probably need to take the derivative of that function and plug in $t=8$.  If it's positive then filled if it's negative then drained.  Where are you getting stuck?  Do you know how to take the derivative of this function?

Comment: Can you define $Q(t)$?

Comment: Chances are Q(t) is quantity of water in the tank at any given time (t)

Comment: Yes I believe Q would be quantity.  Im very new to this and trying to learn.  I haven't done much with derivatives yet so am trying to understand this.  Thanks

Comment: @ryanmc if you want to learn calculus get Thomas' Calculus. It's very easy to understand and very intuitive explanations are given.

Comment: @ryanmc do you know the quotient rule?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, i put lots of research into it last night and do understand differentiating using the quotient rule now and have found my solution.  Thanks! your comments helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that $Q(t)$ is a function to describe the height of the water in the reservoir. Now let me provide you with a hint. $Q'(a)$ will tell you the rate at which $Q$ is increasing or decreasing at $a$ seconds.

$Q'(t)= \dfrac{(4t+1)\dfrac{d}{dt}6\sqrt[3]{t}- 6\sqrt[3](t)\dfrac{d}{dt}(4t+1)}{(4t+1)^2}$

Reduce that, input $t=8$, if $Q'(8)>0$ it's being filled. If $Q'(8)<0$ it's draining.

Comment: Your answer may be valid, but I suggest that you elaborate on how the derivative could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: @NoChance I edited it. Hope it's enough for OP.